# Logical Merging of Dataframes

Tags: r

I have two data.frames, of these, one contains the particular order of a number of experiments done in triplicate (DF1 the design table); the other contains the results of these experiments (in triplicate, DF2 the results table).  The first dataframe has a randomised order of experiments, the results table has a different order.

The first six columns of DF1 contain the factors of the experiment, eg temperature, equivalents of reagents, etc...  The results table, DF2, also has the same six columns as well as further columns containing the results of the experiments, eg yields, conversions of various reagents etc ...

The tables differ by the number of rows.  The results table has three less rows than the design table.

How can I merege these two tables so that I have the results attached to the design such that the experiment parameters in the design table match the appropriate results in the experiment table.

DF1

```
T1  A1  B1
T2  A1  B1
T1  A2  B1
T2  A2  B1
T1  A1  B2
T2  A1  B2
T1  A2  B2
T2  A2  B2
```

but in triplicate.

DF2

```
T1  A2  B2  1
T1  A2  B1  3
T2  A2  B1  3
T1  A1  B1  1
T2  A1  B2  2
T2  A2  B2  2
T2  A1  B1  2
```

again in triplicate, noting that there is one less row.  Note that there are more results columns than the one displayed.

As to the point of all of this work: I'm looking at whether or not I can apply the package RcmdrPlugin.DoE to some real data.

As to what I've tried ... well,   I thought about using sapply, cbind and ifelse with the logic function

```
sapply(
DF3 <- ifelse( DF1[,1] == DF2[,1] | DF1[,2] == DF2[,2] | DF2[,3] == DF2[,3],
cbind(DF1, DF2[,3]), NA)
)
```

I've got a propblem with the NA in this code.  But before I got to the NA I found that I had a argument 'FUN' is missing error.

I think I'm either way off the mark or very close to the answer, but which of the two.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Edit ... a sample of seven rows of the data that I have where I've changed the headings to A, B, C, and D which are the ones common to both data.frames.

```
      run.no run.no.std.rp Block.ccd   A     B C     D
C0.17      1         C0.17         0 400 147.5 5 2.675
C0.7       2          C0.7         0 450 120.0 2 4.000
C0.6       3          C0.6         0 350 175.0 2 4.000
C0.3       4          C0.3         0 450 120.0 8 4.000
C0.4       5          C0.4         0 350 120.0 8 4.000
C0.16      6         C0.16         0 350 120.0 2 1.350
C0.15      7         C0.15         0 450 120.0 2 1.350
```

The other data.frame has headings A, B, C, and D as well as columns with yield, conversion and other results.  I need the first data.frame to be exactly as shown with the yield etc tagged on to the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title mentions "merge" but you seem to have not tried the `merge` function. (Or am I missing something?)

Here are your first two example `data.frame`s:

```
DF1 <- structure(list(T1 = c("T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T2"
  ), A1 = c("A1", "A2", "A2", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2"), B1 = c("B1", 
  "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2")), .Names = c("T1", "A1", 
  "B1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

DF2 <- structure(list(T1 = c("T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2"), A2 = c("A2", 
  "A2", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A1"), B2 = c("B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", 
  "B2", "B1"), X1 = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("T1", 
  "A2", "B2", "X1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Here's how you use `merge` from base R. The `by.x` and `by.y` arguments should include the names of the columns that you should have in common in both `data.frame`s. The `all` argument says to not drop any "blanks" but fill them with `NA` instead.

```
merge(DF1, DF2, 
      by.x = c("T1", "A1", "B1"), 
      by.y = c("T1", "A2", "B2"), 
      all = TRUE)
#   T1 A1 B1 X1
# 1 T1 A1 B1  1
# 2 T1 A1 B2 NA
# 3 T1 A2 B1  3
# 4 T1 A2 B2 NA
# 5 T2 A1 B1  2
# 6 T2 A1 B2  2
# 7 T2 A2 B1  3
# 8 T2 A2 B2  2
```

Here's the result of `merge` on the two `data.frame`s that Arun created. Notice that we don't need to specify which columns to merge on since they have common column names.

```
merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)
#   V1 V2 V3 run.no run.no.std.rp Block.ccd   A     B  C     D
# 1 T1 A1 B1      4          C0.3         0 450 120.0  8 4.000
# 2 T1 A1 B2     NA          <NA>        NA  NA    NA NA    NA
# 3 T1 A2 B1      2          C0.7         0 450 120.0  2 4.000
# 4 T1 A2 B2      1         C0.17         0 400 147.5  5 2.675
# 5 T2 A1 B1      7         C0.15         0 450 120.0  2 1.350
# 6 T2 A1 B2      5          C0.4         0 350 120.0  8 4.000
# 7 T2 A2 B1      3          C0.6         0 350 175.0  2 4.000
# 8 T2 A2 B2      6         C0.16         0 350 120.0  2 1.350
```

Comment: Will try this and report back, @anada

Comment: Both answers work on the example data given.  Thanks for your help.  I ticked both answers but the default settings only allow one answer to prevail.  Particular thanks to @Arun for drawing my attention to data.tables.

Comment: When applied to my real data set I got 'Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns' Here's my attempt, attempt.1 <- merge(core.structure, core.results, by.x = c(core.structure$6, core.structure$7, core.structure$8, core.structure$9), by.y = c(core.results[,2], core.results[,3], core.results[,6], core.results[,4]), all = TRUE).  My unique patterns in the first DF are in columns 6,7,8, 9 while they are in columns 2,3,6,4 for my second DF.

Comment: @user1945827, what are the *names* of columns 6-9 and 2, 3, 6, 4? You can try one of two things: (1) use the column *names*, as I have done in my examples; (2) rename the relevant columns in each dataset so that they are the same (in other words, column 6 in DF1 should have the same name as column 2 in DF2).

Comment: Your, @anaanda suggestion, '(1) use the column names, as I have done in my examples' works, in that no errors have been returned.  Thanks

Comment: But it doesn't put the results into the required order; ie, yields from one set of experimental conditions don't tally with those from another set.

Comment: @user1945827, please read `?merge` and see if anything there helps answer your question. In particular, you might want to add the argument `sort = FALSE` to `merge` and see if that solves your problem. Otherwise, it's not that difficult to sort a `data.frame` using `order()`.

Comment: sort = FALSE is starting to make sense ... but.  merge(x,y, by.x = c("E","F","G","H"), puts these columns at the very beginning of the table.  Instead of "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H" plus columns from 'y'; I have, "E","F","G","H","A","B","C","D" plus columns from 'y'.

Answer (score 5):

The `data.table` package (that allows for x[y] syntax) makes this job incredibly easy. Assuming `df1` and `df2` are your data.frames:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key=c("V1","V2","V3"))
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key=c("V1","V2","V3"))
dt2[dt1]

#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1: T1 A1 B1  1
# 2: T1 A1 B2 NA
# 3: T1 A2 B1  3
# 4: T1 A2 B2  1
# 5: T2 A1 B1  2
# 6: T2 A1 B2  2
# 7: T2 A2 B1  3
# 8: T2 A2 B2  2
```

gives you the desired result.

**Edit:** I've used your edited data and it seems to work.

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
                     .Label = c("T1", "T2"), class = "factor"), 
                 V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
                 .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor"), 
                 V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                 .Label = c("B1", "B2"), class = "factor")), 
                 .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                      .Label = c("T1", "T2"), class = "factor"), 
                      V2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                      .Label = c("A1", "A2"), class = "factor"), 
                      V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
                      .Label = c("B1", "B2"), class = "factor"), 
                      run.no = 1:7, 
                      run.no.std.rp = structure(c(3L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 1L), 
                      .Label = c("C0.15", "C0.16", "C0.17", "C0.3", "C0.4", "C0.6", "C0.7"), 
                      class = "factor"), 
                      Block.ccd = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                      A = c(400L, 450L, 350L, 450L, 350L, 350L, 450L), 
                      B = c(147.5, 120, 175, 120, 120, 120, 120), 
                      C = c(5L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L), 
                      D = c(2.675, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1.35, 1.35)), 
                      .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "run.no", "run.no.std.rp", 
                      "Block.ccd", "A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                      row.names = c("C0.17", "C0.7", "C0.6", "C0.3", "C0.4", 
                      "C0.16", "C0.15"), class = "data.frame")

require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key=c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key=c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
dt2[dt1]
#    V1 V2 V3 run.no run.no.std.rp Block.ccd   A     B  C     D
# 1: T1 A1 B1      4          C0.3         0 450 120.0  8 4.000
# 2: T1 A1 B2     NA            NA        NA  NA    NA NA    NA
# 3: T1 A2 B1      2          C0.7         0 450 120.0  2 4.000
# 4: T1 A2 B2      1         C0.17         0 400 147.5  5 2.675
# 5: T2 A1 B1      7         C0.15         0 450 120.0  2 1.350
# 6: T2 A1 B2      5          C0.4         0 350 120.0  8 4.000
# 7: T2 A2 B1      3          C0.6         0 350 175.0  2 4.000
# 8: T2 A2 B2      6         C0.16         0 350 120.0  2 1.350
```

Comment: It may have done with the sample data that I gave but when I use the code with the data I have, I get an erro.  Error in '[.data.table'(dt2,dt1): typeof x.Temp (double) != typeof i.Block.ccd (integer)

Comment: Hi @Arun, my proposed table has 102 rows.  Is the code above the only way to convert the data.frame to a data.table?

Comment: Hi @Arun, my real data returns, 'Error in `[.data.table`(dt2, dt1) : 
  x.'Temp' is a factor column being joined to i.'Temp' which is type 'integer'. Factor columns must join to factor or character columns.'